# Auto Correct software for Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: keyboard, 21.10, auto-completion

Windows 11 has been released with new features, one of which is a special kind of grammar checking software. How can I get a similar thing in Ubuntu 21.10?

I want autocorrect to work in all applications (especially gedit and Vivaldi). I am using the default GNOME 40 desktop.

```
OS: Ubuntu 21.10 impish
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.13.0-21-generic
Uptime: 25m
Packages: 2223
Shell: bash 5.1.8
Resolution: 2560x1600
DE: Gnome 
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Orchis
GTK Theme: Orchis-light [GTK2/3]
Icon Theme: Papirus
Font: Ubuntu 11
Disk: 55G / 916G (7%) (SSD) 
CPU:  AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 3.8 x 12
GPU: AMD Radeon™ Graphics
RAM:  2045 / 16384 MB
```

I saw many other posts but none of them works in Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: FYI: Libreoffice has a spell checker. You can also try Grammarly, an online service.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I use Grammarly on my mobile, I don't use Libre Office I use some other office suits for my work. I mainly want a spell checker for Gedit and Vivaldi and a few more apps. I know I can use Grammarly on my PC too,  but not for every app. It works on the Vivaldi web browser but not in other apps. The client is made only for Windows and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the `gedit` Spell Checker plugin...

[image]

Comment: What about other apps? Thanks for the `gedit` information. +1

Comment: @someone Open `Synaptic` and search for "spell checker". See `aspell`, and others.